# How to display voltages on LCD of a PIC16F877A embedded system?

Tags: c, embedded, system

I am writing code to display voltage data on the LCD on a PIC16F877A. To observe the values on the display, it needs a delay but when I use the delay function, it gets stuck. When I change the pot value, it will not show during the observation delay. So I need assistance and guidance to introduce delay.  When I change the value of the pot, I should change it during a 5 second delay. I share my code below:

```
// Lcd pinout settings
sbit LED1 at RB4_bit;
sbit LCD_RS at RD2_bit;
sbit LCD_EN at RD3_bit;
sbit LCD_D4 at RD4_bit;
sbit LCD_D5 at RD5_bit;
sbit LCD_D6 at RD6_bit;
sbit LCD_D7 at RD7_bit;
//sbit SW at RB1_bit;
// Pin direction
sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISD2_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISD3_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISD4_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISD5_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISD6_bit;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISD7_bit;


unsigned short count,pls;
unsigned char ch,bh;
long tlong,blong;

void adc1_config();
void adc2_config();
int adc1_prcs();
int adc2_prcs();

void main()
{
adc1_config();
adc2_config();
ADC_Init();
Lcd_Init();
Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);
adc1_prcs();
adc2_prcs();
Lcd_Out(1,1,"VAC-IN : ");
Lcd_Out(2,1,"VAC-OUT: ");
delay_ms(5000);
// here i want delay to adjust input voltage and calibrate.
// delay does not work here bcoz adc value stuck due to delay function.
// suugest proven technique to avoid delay.
TRISB.F4 = 0;
while(1)
{
Lcd_Out(1,1,"info page");
Lcd_Out(2,4,"123456789");
delay_ms(5000);
//same scenario occur here
Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
adc1_prcs();
adc2_prcs();
Lcd_Out(1,1,"VAC-IN : ");
Lcd_Out(2,1,"VAC-OUT: ");
delay_ms(5000);
Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
 // and here also

 }
}
```

I tried using the mikroC compiler.

Comment: Your question appears to be just "how do I create a delay?",  But you title suggests something else.  What are you asking?  All your delays appear to be 5000ms - where does the 4 second delay mentioned in the question occur?

Comment: I want simply create delay where i mentioned in code as a comment

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking or what you are trying to achieve since you have not provided complete code.  It is not clear where you are either reading the ADC or displaying its value.   What for example does `adc1_prcs()` do? Any solution may involve modification of that.  I am assuming that you want that "process" to continue while maintaining the display.  The solution is likely not to delay, but to poll the time-elapsed and update the display when it is time to do so.  And you should certainly separate the ADC read from the data display - just for good design.

Comment: In adc1_prcs() just conversaion part calling in main... That not issue.. its perfectly fine without delay but changing pot value. But when i use delay function to display multiple things at some interval of time the adc value not update as delay present tbere . So ineed delay using timer or interrupt

Comment: Still not clear.  If you are only displaying the value after a delay, why does it matter that you are not reading it continuously?  There is still not code here actually displaying the value, and you have not addressed _all_ my points.  Where is the value displayed?  Is it even displayed?  Is displaying it part of the question?  Or is it just about the timing?  Where is the value to be displayed?  I am writing an answer, but it is currently on a great deal of guess work on exactly what you are asking.  I appreciate that English may not be a first language.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to avoid delay altogether - during a delay without multi-threading support, the CPU stalls doing no useful work (unless performed in interrupt handlers).  One solution to that (short of an RTOS) is rather than delay, simply poll a free-running counter of *elapsed_time* and perform actions whatever they become "*due*".

I am no PIC developer and I have synthesised the following from information on various sites - it may not be correct and most of it was for Microchip's XC8 compiler and may need some changes for MikroC - I think they have a different naming convention for peripheral register access structures.

So given the following 1ms tick implementation using TIMER 0:

```
#define FOSC_FREQ 4000000  //4MHz

// 1/1000 seconds 24=56 prescaler
#define TIMER_1MS (256 - FOSC_FREQ / (1024 * 1000) ) 

static volatile uint32_t ms_tick = 0 ;
uint32_t initMsTick()
{
    OPTION_REGbits.PSA = 0; 
    OPTION_REGbits.PS = 0b111;  //Set the prescaler to 1:256
    OPTION_REGbits.T0CS = 0;
    INTCONbits.T0IF = 0;        //Clear the Timer 0 interrupt flag
    TMR0 = TIMER_1MS;           //Load counter for 1ms tick
    INTCONbits.T0IE = 1;        //Enable the Timer 0 interrupt
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;         //Set the Global Interrupt Enable
}

uint32_t getMsTick()
{
    uint32_t now = ms_tick ;
    while( now != ms_tick )
    {
        now = ms_tick ;
    }
    return now ;
}

void interrupt()
{
    if( INTCONbits.T0IF) 
    {
        INTCONbits.T0IF = TIMER_1MS ;
        ms_tick++ ;
    }
}
```

you might then create a timer interface thus:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t ref ;
    uinr32_t period ;
} timer_t ;

void startTimer( timer_t* timer, uint32_t period )
{
    timer->ref = getMsTick() ;
    timer->period = period ;
}

bool hasTimerExpired( timer_t* timer )
{
    return (getMsTick() - timer->ref) >= timer->period ;
}
```

Then in your application for example:

```
    adc1_config();
    adc2_config();
    ADC_Init();
    Lcd_Init();
    Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);

    TRISB.F4 = 0;
    
    timer_t display_time ;
    for(;;)
    {
        Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
        Lcd_Out(1,1,"VAC-IN : ");
        Lcd_Out(2,1,"VAC-OUT: ");
        startTimer( &display_time, 4000u ) ;
        while( !hasTimerExpired( &display_time ) )
        {
            adc1_prcs();
            adc2_prcs();
        }

        Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
        Lcd_Out(1,1,"info page");
        Lcd_Out(2,4,"123456789");
        timer_t display_time ;
        startTimer( &display_time, 4000u ) ;
        while( !hasTimerExpired( &display_time ) )
        {
            adc1_prcs();
            adc2_prcs();
        }
    }
```

Note that I have removed your unnecessary initial display by making it the first display in the loop.  It may have been there for a reason, but I cannot see it.

This can be simplified given:

```
void displayPage( int page )
{
    Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
    switch( page )
    {
        case 0 :
        {
            Lcd_Out(1,1,"VAC-IN : ");
            Lcd_Out(2,1,"VAC-OUT: ");
        } 
        break ;

        case 1 :
        {
            Lcd_Out(1,1,"info page");
            Lcd_Out(2,4,"123456789");
        }
        break ;
    }
}
```

then

```
    int page = 0 ;
    displayPage( page ) ;
    timer_t display_time ;
    startTimer( &display_time, 4000u ) ;

    for(;;)
    {
        // Read ADCs continuously
        adc1_prcs();
        adc2_prcs();

        // Every four seconds flip display
        if( hasTimerExpired( &display_timer ) )
        {
            startTimer( &display_time, 4000u )
            page = page == 0 ? 1 : 0 ;
            displayPage( page ) ;
        }
    }
```

Note that the timer interface allows multiple concurrent timers of differing expiry periods so that you can have code like:

```
#define TASK1_PERIOD 1000u ; // 1 second
#define TASK2_PERIOD  333u ; // 1/3 second

timer_t t1, t2 ;
startTimer( &t1, TASK1_PERIOD ) ; 
startTimer( &t2, TASK2_PERIOD ) ;  // 1/3 second

for(;;)
{
    if( hasTimerExpired( &t1 ) )
    {
        startTimer( &t1, TASK1_PERIOD ) ; // restart
        
        // Things to do every second here... 
    }

    if( hasTimerExpired( &t2 ) )
    {
        startTimer( &t2, TASK2_PERIOD ) ; // restart
        
        // Things to do every 1/3 second here... 
    }

    // Things to do continuously here...
}
```

The architecture lends itself to implementing time-triggered state-machines, and periodic run-to-completion non-blocking functions.

Comment: Big Thanks  to @Clifford to understand my requirements. So i need to understand your code architecture. One thing i want to ask that you created display function and then put adc in continuous loop. So is this create delay for 4 second and then display voltage value or info whatever it is?

Comment: The display function does not "work", it uses the same apparently "dummy" display in your question.  It is not clear what you actually want to do there - you never answered my question about that in the comments.  The code using the display function calls the ADC functions continuously but calls `displayPage()` every 4 seconds, toggling the page index on each call.  That may not be what you wanted, but it remains less than clear in your question.  Even if it is an incomplete solution however, the principle of non-blocking timing is the take-home here.

Comment: _"is this create delay for 4 second...?"_- there is no delay, that is the point, elapsed time is polled until 4 seconds has passed, then it changes the display, and restarts the timer.

Comment: Did you intentionally make timet_t instead of timer_t? In structure. And plz explain how to access display time pointer bcoz it gives me error. Thanks

Comment: It was a typo.  The code should be regarded as illustrative only, I have not tested or even compiled it.  Apply your intuition over obvious typos.

Comment: But i am not getting it. Display_time pointer useful but it gives error in declaration

Comment: @AfzalAnsari as I said, none of this is tested or compiled, it is the general pattern and _design_ principles that you should take from this. I do not have your toolchain or target, you have to adapt the _idea_ to suit your needs.  Moreover unless you tell me the error, I cannot really help you.